# Ruby: conditional matrix? case with multiple conditions?

Tags: ruby, matrix, conditional-statements, switch-statement

In ruby, I was wondering if there's a way to do the following:

I have basically a matrix of four possible outcomes:

```
A is True, B is True
A is True, B is False
A is False, B is True
A is False, B is False
```

I'd like to write a test for this in the cleanest possible "ruby way".

I was hoping to do something like

```
case[A,B]
  when A && B then ...
  when A && !B then ...
  when !A && B then ...
  when !A && !B then ...
end
```

... but that doesn't work. So, what's the best way to handle this kind of situation?

Comment: the standard indentation puts *when* at the *case* level.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Boolean case (with no expression in the `case`, it returns the first branch with a *truthy* `when_expr`):

```
result = case
when A && B then ...
when A && !B then ...
when !A && B then ...
when !A && !B then ...
end
```

Matching case (with an expression in the `case`, it returns the first branch that satisfies the predicate `when_expr === case_expr`):

```
result = case [A, B]
when [true, true] then ...
when [true, false] then ...
when [false, true] then ...
when [false, false] then ...
end
```

Comment: Ok, the second option is what I was looking for. Awesome!

Comment: Great second solution.

Comment: Awesome! It's a truth table!

Answer (score 23):

If you're looking for a case with one condition but multiple matchers..

```
case @condition
  when "a" or "b"
    # do something
  when "c"
    # do something
end
```

..then you **actually need this**:

```
case @condition
  when "a", "b"
    # do something
  when "c"
    # do something
end
```

This can be rewritten as

```
case @condition
  when ("a" and "b")
    # do something
  when "c"
    # do something
end
```

But this is somewhat counter-intuitive, as it's equivalent to

```
if @condition == "a" or @condition == "b"
```

Answer (score 9):

Not sure if there's a standard Ruby way, but you can always turn them into a number:

```
val = (a ? 1 : 0) + (b ? 2 : 0)
case val
  when 0 then ...
  when 1 then ...
  when 2 then ...
  when 3 then ...
end
```

or have an array of arrays of procs and do

```
my_procs[a][b].call()
```

Comment: +1 for the old school C trick. I'd use `0b01` and `0b10` to make it clear that you're really building a bitmap rather than just adding integers.

Comment: if you feel fancy: *[a, b].each_with_index.map { |x, i| (x ?  1 : 0) << i }.inject(:+)* ;-)

Comment: rudimental thing, this is not a community-driven way, you'd better open an issue and ask core team to look at it too @andrew