# Multi-parameter case

Tags: ruby

I want to create a `case` checking multiple parameters.

"[Ruby: conditional matrix? case with multiple conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111106/ruby-conditional-matrix-case-with-multiple-conditions)" 
is basically it with one twist:  The second parameter can be one of three values, `a`, `b`, `nil`.

I was hoping to just extend the `when` conditions to be something like:

```
 result = case [A, B]
  when [true, ‘a’] then …
  when [true, ‘b’] then …
  when [true, B.nil?] then …
end
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I think the third clause should have [true, nil].  Also, it is not clear what is your question

Comment: I think you answered it with [true, nil] ;-)

Comment: If all your conditions start with `true`, then don't include the test of `A`, instead only test for your `B` values. Otherwise you're needlessly slowing the tests. If they don't, then I think you'll end up with a long list of `when` statements that don't improve readability/maintainability or speed. At that point I'd probably break it down into sections or figure out a more readable solution.

Answer (score 1):

In the comments is already the answer for your specific test for `nil`:

```
result = case [A, B]
  when [true, 'a'] then …
  when [true, 'b'] then …
  when [true, nil] then …
end
```

But your question inspired me for a more extended question: What if the 2nd parameter could be anything? E.g. you have this decision table:

```
A   B   result
------------------
a   b   true
a   _   halftrue
_   b   halftrue
else    false
```

where `_` is a indicator for *anything*

A possible solution would be a class, that is equal to everything:

```
class Anything
  include Comparable
  def <=>(x);0;end
end

[
  %w{a b},
  %w{a x},
  %w{x b},
  %w{x y},
].each{|a,b|

  result = case [a, b]
    when ['a', 'b'] then true
    when ['a', Anything.new] then :halftrue
    when [Anything.new, 'b'] then :halftrue
    else false
  end

  puts "%s %s: %s" % [a,b,result]
}
```

The result:

```
a b: true
a x: halftrue
x b: halftrue
x y: false
```